# Что такое helloworld.py~?

Tags: python, ubuntu

В Ubuntu в дериктории py у меня лежит файл helloworld.py
ls выдает, что у меня их там 2 - ls py
helloworld.py  helloworld.py~
Что означает helloworld.py~ ?

Comment: vim-ом не пользовались? А если пользовались, выходили из него?

Comment: Нет пока) Я еще его побаиваюсь)

Comment: Это копия файла создаваемая вашим редактором. `gedit`, скорей всего?

Comment: Создал другую папку, создал там файл, открыл в gedit, но там он один.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это значит, что ты пользовался каким-то редактором, который сохраняет в качестве бэкапа предыдущую копию как раз с именем `имя файла~`. В `gedit` это отключается в `Правка -> Настройка -> Редактор -> Создавать запасную копию файла перед сохранением`.

Comment: Точно. Спасибо! Как-то нужно теперь закрывать тему? Недавно просто на stackoverflow

Comment: Не надо закрывать. Пусть висит - в этом вся суть стака. Просто закрой вкладку браузера.

Comment: Просто у ответа, решившего проблему я ставлю галочку, да?

Comment: Да. И всё. Ну можешь дополнительно пометить как полезный.